# MouseListener not triggering for custom JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, mouselistener

I want to make a Swing program with icon tiles that play certain sounds when you click on them. For this I created the class:

```
public class Item extends JLabel implements MouseListener {
    public Item(String s) {
           // constructor setting background icon and private field with the sound to play
    }

   public void playSound(); //plays the sound

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Clicked");
        this.playSound();

    }


    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Pressed");

    }


    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Then I create a custom `JFrame` class:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9221468315661092752L;
    public static final int DEFAULT_FRAME_WIDTH=400;
    public static final int DEFAULT_FRAME_HEIGHT=400;
    private GridLayout gridLayout;

    private ArrayList<Item> tiles=new ArrayList<Item>();


    public Frame() {
        super("Title");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(DEFAULT_FRAME_WIDTH,DEFAULT_FRAME_HEIGHT));
        gridLayout=new GridLayout(4,4,10,10);
        setLayout(gridLayout);
        addItems();

    }

    public void addItems() {
        Item item=new Item("name");
        Item item2=new Item("name");
        tiles.add(item);
        tiles.add(item2);
        this.add(item);
        this.add(item2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Frame frame=new Frame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

The tiles show normally in the grid layout, however the problem is that the mouse listener doesn't work. The `println()` I put at `mouseClicked()` and `mousePressed()` is not called.

I could try to add a `MouseListener` to the `Item` class, so that `Item` has a `MouseListener`, but I wonder what is wrong with the above code.

Comment: `I could try to add a MouseListener to the Item class, so that Item has a MouseListener, but I wonder what is wrong with the above code` - and that is exactly the problem you didn't add a MouseListener to the instance when you create the class. A component doesn't listen to any event unless you tell it to. Implementing the MouseListener interface does not tell it to listen to MouseEvents. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for a working example.

Comment: An sans serif button/action listener with an icon will do everything the label /mouse combo. does, but also respond to keyboard input.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. One, your JLabels do not show (although I'm not sure if that was intentionally left out). Two, you never add a mouse listener. You can accomplish this by adding two statements to the constructor, without making any extra classes:

```
public Item(String s) {
   super(s); //initializes the text and display using JLabel's constructor
   addMouseListener(this); //uses the reference of this Item as a MouseListener
}
```

Comment: Or you could read the tutorial so you don't have to ask a question every time you come up with a little problem. That is why a link to the tutorial was given in the comment. The link to the tutorial should be bookmarked for future use. The tutorial will also show you how to better structure your code so you don't extend JFrame and the components are created on the EDT. Start with a good working example and then make changes.

Comment: You most certainly could.